# NameError on global variables when multiprocessing, only in subdirectory

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, nameerror

I have a main process which uses execfile and runs a script in a child process. This works fine unless the script is in another directory -- then everything breaks down.

This is in `mainprocess.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

m = "subdir\\test.py"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target = execfile, args = (m,))
    p.start()
```

Then in a subdirectory aptly named subdir, I have `test.py`

```
import time

def foo():
    print time.time()

foo()
```

When I run `mainprocess.py`, I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

but the issue isn't limited to module names -- sometimes I'll get an error on a function name on other pieces of code.

I've tried importing time in `mainprocess.py` and also inside the `if` statement there, but neither has any effect.

One way of avoiding the error (I haven't tried this), is to copy `test.py` into the parent directory and insert a line in the file to `os.chdir` back to the original directory. However, this seems rather sloppy.

So what is happening?

Comment: Why not use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change your Process initialization:

```
p = Process(target=execfile, args=(m, {}))
```

Honestly, I'm not entirely sure why this works. I know it has something to do with which dictionary (locals vs. globals) that the **time** import is added to. It seems like when your import is made in test.py, it's treated like a local variable, because the following works:

```
import time        # no foo() anymore
print(time.time()) # the call to time.time() is in the same scope as the import
```

However, the following also works:

```
import time
def foo():
    global time
    print(time.time())
foo()
```

This second example shows me that the import is still assigned to *some* kind of global namespace, I just don't know how or why.

If you call execfile() normally, rather than in a subprocess, everything runs fine, and in fact, you can then use the time module any place after the call to execfile() call in your main process because time has been brought into the same namespace. I think that since you're launching it in a subprocess there is no module-level namespace for the import to be assigned to (execfile doesn't create a module object when called). I think that when we add the empty dictionary to the call to execfile, we're adding supplying the *global dictionary* argument, thus giving the import mechanism a global namespace to assign the name **time** to.

Some links for background:

1) [Tutorial page on namespaces and scope](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html)
- look here for builtin, global, and local namespace explanations first

2) [Python docs on execfile command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)

3) [A very similar question on a non-SO site](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/145029-Execfile%28%29-do-not-see-the-global-scope)